# codeigniter login with hash password PASSWORD_BCRYPT

Tags: php, codeigniter, hash, bcrypt

so I'm new to C.I and I have this kind of code from a tutorial for me it is clean. I manage to insert a hash password using "PASSWORD_BCRYPT" and it store to database successfully my problem is i can manage to full out the correct so that my login model will be successful.

MODEL FOR INSERT

```
public function insert_user(){

$password = $this->input->post('Password');
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$data = array(
'Username' => $this->input->post('Username'),
'Password' => $hash,
'Position' => $this->input->post('Position'),
'Office' => $this->input->post('Office'),
); 
print_r($data);

return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
```

}

MODEL FOR LOGIN

```
public function login(){

$this->db->where('Username', $this->input->post('Username', true));
$this->db->where('Password', $this->input->post('Password', true));
$result = $this->db->get('users');

if($result->num_rows() == 1){

    return $result->row_array();
    
}else{
    return false;
}
```

controller

```
public function log_in(){

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">','</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Password', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

        $page = "login";

        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
            show_404();
        }
        
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page);

        }else{

            $user_id = $this->Page_model->login();

            if($user_id){

                $user_data = array(
                    'Username' => $user_id['Username'],
                    'Position' => $user_id['Position'].' '.$user_id['Username'],
                    'Office' => $user_id['Office'],
                    'logged_in' => true

                );
            
                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('user_log', 'You are now loged in as '
                .$this->session->Position);
                redirect(base_url());
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('failed', 'Username/Password not match');
                redirect(base_url().'log_in');

            }


            
           

        }
}
```

is someone give me some tips how to make it working.

I try someway but as you expect no successful at all.

Comment: You should read their [document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php). There are a lot of examples in PHP document that is easy to understand. How can you use `password_hash()` without `password_verify()`?

Comment: Also duplicated with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50760699/password-hash-and-in-codeigniter).

Comment: @vee please be gently on your reply, do you think i post this problem if i'm not trying anything like reading and make test in this document 'Password Hashing Functions' your comment is so rude, you even not posting any of your idea. i'm new to C.I so please consider that before you hit you keyboard.

Comment: @vee i dong need your harsh reply i need some idea on how it work.

Answer (score 0):

Ass @vee said its better to always check the documentation.

Below explanation is quoted from the documentation:

> The following algorithms are currently supported:
>
> - PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length
>   of the result from using this identifier can change over time.
>   Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column
>   that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good
>   choice).
> - PASSWORD_BCRYPT - Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the hash. This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the
>   "$2y$" identifier. The result will always be a 60 character string, or
>   false on failure.
> - PASSWORD_ARGON2I - Use the Argon2i hashing algorithm to create the hash. This algorithm is only available if PHP has been compiled with
>   Argon2 support.
> - PASSWORD_ARGON2ID - Use the Argon2id hashing algorithm to create the hash. This algorithm is only available if PHP has been compiled
>   with Argon2 support.

For the 3rd parameter options for password_hash cost variable could be used

> cost (int) - which denotes the algorithmic cost that should be used.
> Examples of these values can be found on the [crypt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) page.

- CRYPT_BLOWFISH - Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z". Using characters outside of this range in the salt will cause crypt() to return a zero-length string. The two digit cost parameter is the base-2 logarithm of the iteration count for the underlying Blowfish-based hashing algorithm and must be in range 04-31, values outside this range will cause crypt() to fail. "$2x$" hashes are potentially weak; "$2a$" hashes are compatible and mitigate this weakness. For new hashes, "$2y$" should be used.

When using [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) no need to hash the user's entry before comparing it with the hashed saved password. As everytime the password is hashed it generates gives different hashed output, but the [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) de-hashes and compares the input and previously stored hashed version. Example from the official documentation.

```
<?php
// See the password_hash() example to see where this came from.
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>
```